# Kotlin: How to call class properties in main function and print the result?

Tags: class, kotlin

I am new to coding. I am trying to understand how code works in Kotlin. Today I was reading about 
 Class and Inheritance. Now I am trying to understand few things from below code:

1. **Why no overriding for using class properties in copyAddress function?**
2. **How to print the ' result '. In the main function, I am unable to understand what to provide** 
     **parameter while calling copyAddress function?**

**This is my code:**

```
package Spice

class Address {
    var name: String = "Holmes, Sherlock"
    var street: String = "Baker"
    var city: String = "London"
    var state: String? = null
    var zip: String = "123456"
}

fun copyAddress(address: Address): Address {
    val result = Address()
    result.name = address.name
    result.street = address.street
    return result
}

fun main(){
    val a = copyAddress(address = Spice.Address())
    print(a)
}
```

Comment: 1. Because all the properties of `Address` are public, so anyone that has an `Address` instance can access its properties.

Comment: I'm not sure why you brought up inheritance, since there's no inheritance in your code. In case you're referring to the `: Address` after `copyAddress`, that's just specifying the return type of the function, i.e. that `copyAddress` will return an `Address`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Because the "Address" `class` and properties is not `open`. It's final class so you can not [inherit](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html) it. The `override` keyword is used in inherited(from `interface`, `open class` or `open var`) classes.   Here is an example:

   ```
    open class HomeAddress{  
    open var streetName : String = ""  
    }    

    class Address:HomeAddress(){  
    override var streetName : String = ""  
    }

    fun main(){
    var address = Address()
    address.streetName = "Baker"
    println(address.streetName)
    }
   ```
2. The `fun copyAddress(address: Address): Address` line refers to your function return a Address class type. I'm cropping your code a little bit.

   ```
   class Address {
    var streetName: String = "Baker"
    var name:String = "Holmes, Sherlock"
   }

   fun copyAddress(address: Address): Address {
    return address
   }

   fun main(){
    val a = Address()
    val myAddress = copyAddress(a)
    println(myAddress.streetName)
    println(myAddress.name)
   }
   ```